# How to display a large XML file (>21MB) in a tree view quickly

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, xmlreader

I need to display a large XML file (>21MB) in a tree view control in a C# Windows Form application. I have written the code which is working for small XML files but when i am trying to open a BIG XML file (>1 MB), its taking too much of time.
 Can anyone suggest how i can optimise this and suggest me any changes or alternatives to achieve this.

Below is the code snippet:

```
private void CreateTreeViewFromATXML(string strSrcFileName)
        {
            XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNode xmlnode ;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(strSrcFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc.Load(fs);
            xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
            XMLTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
            XMLTreeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name));
            TreeNode tNode ;
            tNode = XMLTreeView.Nodes[0];
            AddNode(xmlnode, tNode);
        }


    private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
    {
        //XmlNode xNode ;
        TreeNode tNode ;
        XmlNodeList nodeList ;
        int i = 0;
        if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;

            foreach (XmlNode XNode in inXmlNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                tNode = new TreeNode(XNode.Name);
                inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(tNode);
                AddNode(XNode, tNode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of building the entire treeview up-front, build it lazily. When the user clicks a node, build its children.

Comment: I would also consider using a worker/background thread for parsing and generating tree nodes, as it isn't desirable to lockup the UI thread processing considerable chunks of data like this.

Answer (score 4):

I would wrap your code like this:

```
XMLTreeView.BeginUpdate();
try
{
    CreateTreeViewFromATXML(strSrcFileName);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Handle any error
}
finally
{
    XMLTreeView.EndUpdate();
}
```

If you're not in an update block it's repainting the GUI on every node add and that's expensive.  You also have recursion in `AddNode` but if the XML isn't too deeply nested it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using XDocument and XML to Linq for a faster parsing. You can use the following code to parse the XML:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XMLFile);

var item = from items in xdoc.Element("EPICORTLOG").Descendants("POS")
                       where (string)items.Element("Id") == strSelectedPOSID
                       select items.Elements("TRADE").Elements("ITEM").ToList().ToList();
```

You can then follow the explanation in the following link to parse the XML:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564
The article above will explain the XML to LINQ programming. Using the above method you can load XML files as big as 10MB in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I used TreeView component to implement my HTML editor in C#, I used serialized data structure to impove the performance to open and save a XML file.
From my experience , using this structure and serialize read and write file can open  file up to 20M byes within 2 seconds in my computer. This solution can open a XML file over 2G bytes in my C# application. Hope this solution can help you better.

Example to define Serializable Structure for TreeView and TreeNode

```
[Serializable]
public class TreeViewData
{
    public TreeNodeData[] Nodes;
    public TreeViewData(){ }  
    public TreeViewData(TreeView treeview)
    {
       //your code
    }
    public TreeViewData(TreeNode treenode)
    {
       //your code 
    }
    public void PopulateTree(TreeView treeview)
    {
        //your code 
    }
    public void PopulateSubTree(TreeNode treenode)
    {
         //your code 
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class TreeNodeData
{
    public string Text;
    public int ImageIndex;
    public int SelectedImageIndex;
    public string Tag;
    public TreeNodeData[] Nodes;
    public TreeNodeData() {}  
    public TreeNodeData(TreeNode node)
    {
          // your code 
    }
    public TreeNode ToTreeNode()
    {
     // your code 
    }
}
```

Example to serialize read XML file

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(TreeViewData));
System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Open);
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(file);
TreeViewData treeData = (TreeViewData)ser.Deserialize(reader);
treeData.PopulateTree(TreeView1);
```

Example to serialize write XML file

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(TreeViewData));
System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(strFilename,   System.IO.FileMode.Create);
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(file, null);
ser.Serialize(writer, new TreeViewData(TreeView1));
```

Comment: Actually, I want to ask the same question as you did.  but my question is how to display a large xml file over 1G bytes in treeview. that is the reason I found your post.